# How to populate my textview with the strings of my video files?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem here on trying to populate my textview with their respective video names and video file size in each file object more dynamically?

Can someone help i'm rather new in android/java...

Comment: Hey Vivian, you need to have more debugging in your app. Your issue does not stand out, could be something simple or more in depth. The best way to get the bottom is to start logging steps to make sure the info is being gathered in the places that you want...